# OpenERP 7 menuitem groups

Tags: python, xml, odoo

i created security part to my model. for that i create ir.model.access.csv file/bpl_security.xml and in **openerp**.py i mapped those.
finally i add restriction to menuitems userwise

But menu not shows for the both parties.i created user and Manager already and create users and tagged them in my csv file also.
please check my code and advice me to do that

[Here](https://github.com/priyankahdp/openerp.git) is my whole code uploaded

> see line 705 in bpl_view.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and found that the error is in your **openerp**.py file. Please change the code in your **openerp**.py file to the following

```
{
    'name': 'ERP System',
    'author': 'Bellvantage (Pvt) Ltd',
    'version': '1.0',
    'depends': ['base', 'hr'],
    'category' : 'Production',
    'summary': 'ERP Information System for Plantation Industry',
    'description': """
    """,
    'data': ['bpl_security.xml',
             'ir.model.access.csv',
             'bpl_worker_registration_sequence.xml',
             'bpl_view.xml',
             ],
    'css':[],
    'images': [],
    'demo': [],
    'installable': True,
    'application' : True,
    'certificate' : '',
    'images': [],
}
```

Comment: thanks Anoma.issue with my earlier tables' mappings.now i created a new DB and user roles working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

As user Anoma said, there is problem in **openerp**.py file, as i seen your code, you have written like

```
'data': [
             'bpl_worker_registration_sequence.xml',
             'bpl_view.xml',
             'security/bpl_security.xml',
             'security/ir.model.access.csv'],
```

as i said in previous answer to put bpl_security.xml,ir.model.access.csv in security folder then change in **openerp**.py file.

so please create a **security** folder in your module bpl.

like

```
bpl
----security
    ---- bpl_security.xml
    ---- ir.model.access.csv
```

so your structure must be like as above describe

Comment: thanks Friend.issue with my earlier tables' mappings.now i created a new DB and user roles working perfectly